# Matplotlib Bar Graph Error - TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['2008-02-19', 10],
        ['2008-03-01', 15],
        ['2009-02-05', 20],
        ['2009-05-10', 40],
        ['2010-10-10', 25],
        ['2010-11-15', 5]
    ],
    columns = ['Date', 'DollarTotal']
)
df
```

[image: df]

I want to plot the total summed by year so I perform the following transformations:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df_Year = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)
df_Year = df_Year.sum('DollarTotal')
df_Year
```

[image: df_Year]

The following code in matplotlib creates the chart below:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df_Year.index, df_Year.values)
ax.set_xlabel("OrderYear")
ax.set_ylabel("$ Total")
ax.set_title("Annual Purchase Amount")
plt.xticks([x for x in df_Year.index], rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

The **problem** occurs when I want to create a **bar graph** using the same DataFrame. By changing the code above from `ax.plot` to `ax.bar`, I get the following error:

[image: error]

I've never come across this error before when plotting in matplotlib. What have I done wrong?

***Please see the answer below by dm2 which solves this problem.***

---

**Edit:**

I just figured out why I never had this problem in the past. It has to do with how I summed the `groupby`. If I replace `df_Year = df_Year.sum('DollarTotal')` with `df_Year = df_Year['DollarTotal'].sum()` then this problem does not occur.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['2008-02-19', 10],
        ['2008-03-01', 15],
        ['2009-02-05', 20],
        ['2009-05-10', 40],
        ['2010-10-10', 25],
        ['2010-11-15', 5]
    ],
    columns = ['Date', 'DollarTotal']
)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df_Year = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)
df_Year = df_Year['DollarTotal'].sum()
df_Year
```

[image: df_sum]

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df_Year.index, df_Year.values)
ax.set_xlabel("OrderYear")
ax.set_ylabel("$ Total")
ax.set_title("Annual Purchase Amount")
plt.xticks([x for x in df_Year.index], rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code/data/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html), the function expects height parameter to be a scalar or a sequence of scalars. `pandas.DataFrame.values` is a two-dimensional array that has rows as its first dimension and columns as its second dimension (even with just one column, it's a two dimensional array), so it's a sequence of arrays. Therefore, if you use `df.values`, you also need to reshape it to the expected sequence (i.e. one-dimensional array) of scalars (i.e. `df.values.reshape(len(df))`).

Or, specifically in your code: `ax.bar(df_Year.index, df_Year.values.reshape(len(df_Year))`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes it works fine without reshaping because your `df_Year` after a groupby and a sum aggregation is actually a pandas Series, and not a DataFrame (which means once you get its values via `df_Year.values`, you get a one-dimensional array instead of a two-dimensional array you were getting before)

Answer (score 3):

You could also just use the [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) of pandas in the following wat:

```
df_Year.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

This will produce:

[image]